# How to increase the speed of Firebase authentication in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have build an app which has login and register features. I also added signout feature and also when the user close and reopens the app firebase checks whether the user is logout or not, but the problem is when i open the app firebase taking lot of time atleast 8-10 second to check whether the user is already logged in or not, so how to increase the speed from firebase so that the user need not wait for 8-10 seconds for more.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
    // Detects when user signed in
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }, onError: (err) {
      print('Error signing in: $err');
    });
    // Reauthenticate user when app is opened
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error signing in: $err');
    });
  }
  handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) async {
    if (account != null) {
      await createUserInFirestore();
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
      configurePushNotifications();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide example code, without it people will not be able to assess the cause of the delay.

Comment: @SamuelCooper I have added the code, so kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this way to check wheater the user is login or not the app

```
Auth auth = Auth();

  await auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) async {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        theme: _themeData(),
        home: user != null
            ? Home(
            userId: user.uid
        )
            : Login(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routes: routes,
      ));
  }).catchError((error) {
    print("Here is ERROR $error");
  });
}
```

It hardly takes one or two seconds to tell the user uid. I hope it will resolve your issue.